# Bash_profile trouble, Have two node module directories

Tags: bash, npm

Im having problems using Sails.js , along with other packages I have installed. I installed them globally and successfully but Im not able to use their commands.

I found out that Im able to fix the problem by adding its path into my bash_profile file but even with that. here is path of recent global packages that I'm trying to get to work right.

```
Miltons-MBP:~ miltonpauta$ npm list -g --depth 0
/Users/miltonpauta/.npm-global/lib
├── @vue/cli@3.9.2
├── @vue/cli-init@3.9.0
├── npm@6.10.0
├── pm2@3.5.1
└── sails@1.2.3
```

in my bash profile, I have it in in the 
(which is located in: /Users/miltonpauta/.bash_profile )

```
export PATH=$PATH:/Users/miltonpauta/.npm-global/lib
```

I tried reloaded it or restarting the file using source and tried to use the commands but its not working

(using bash shell, using mac)

Any ideas? I would really appreciate it.

UPDATE: i think i have two node module directories, which i dont know how happened. I ran npm on the command line and the path its in says..

```
/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm
```

node is installed at:

```
/usr/local/bin/node
```

other node module directory

```
/Users/miltonpauta/.npm-global/lib
```

Does anyone now how to switch the wrong directory items into the right one? Honestly, Im a newbie when it comes to using terminal.

Comment: If this is on Linux, it wouldn't be `Users/...`.  Maybe this is on Windows?

Comment: I'm using mac, Im still confused why two directories were made so I tried to dragging all contents from wrong directory into correct one but it still does not work.